# Do our questions have to be about actual problems that we face?

Tags: discussion, questions

Toward the top of the FAQ on every Stack Exchange site it has this rule prominently highlighted

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

I was wondering if this is actually enforced, or if it even should be enforced. I have asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945276/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-delete-operator-in-javascript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983115/are-perl-regexes-turing-complete) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681090/why-doesnt-int0-0-cause-an-access-violation) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729898/how-can-you-trigger-the-what-the-hell-is-this-jslint-message) [curiousity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491915/why-does-a-b-work-but-ab-doesnt), [or](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly) [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451524/why-arent-and-valid-javascript-variable-names) [just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246051/how-do-i-fix-this-missing-semicolon-syntax-error-in-javascript) [pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do) [rep-whoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769032/what-is-the-optimal-jewish-toenail-cutting-algorithm), that have been accepted by the community.

Are these actually a bad genre of questions that should be closed or even deleted? Is the "actual problems that you face" clause merely just a guideline that can occasionally be broken?

Comment: Seriously though, the [latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer/) happens to discuss this exact thing, in case you're interested.

Comment: You're less likely to run into problems if you only ask questions about real, actual problems. Everything else is subject to the whims of the unwashed masses.

Comment: Is this question about an actual problem that you face?

Comment: @Rosinante No, of course not, this was obviously just a ruse to get more people to upvote my popular questions.

Comment: Well, that's a practical problem. We all need more upvotes.

Comment: My interpretation of that phrase is simply: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you [or someone else could reasonably] face.`

Answer (score 15):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face

is code for

> Please don't ask chatty, [bikeshed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality) questions here.

In fact, the next sentence in the FAQ actually clarifies this:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Encouraging people to focus on actual problems helps them ask questions that are not [polls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), ["gorilla vs. shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)," [shopping recommendations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and the like.

I'm not going to go through all of your examples, but [your first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945276/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-delete-operator-in-javascript) clearly has practical implications for programmers.

Comment: Trying to set up a ["canonical question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote) might also count as a perfectly okay question about a problem that the OP does not in fact face.

Comment: Example canonical question: [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net).

Comment: My [last example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769032/what-is-the-optimal-jewish-toenail-cutting-algorithm) on the other hand, probably has very little, if any, practical implications for programmers.

Comment: @PeterOlson: You asked a legendary question; congratulations. And welcome to the debate we've been having about legendary questions for the last three years. Seriously, though, that question has substantial educational value for programmers, and people clearly find it interesting.

Comment: So... if it's code, why not say what is actually meant? For example, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual, tangible problems". Completely eliminates the confusion.

Comment: @user568458: Because getting people to focus on their pragmatic concerns helps them ask better questions.