# What is "a problem the community faces"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked some folks about why they voted to close [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326785/is-there-a-habit-to-downvote-new-users-by-default). Some people said in the chat that "It also doesn't really solve a problem the community faces Imo, in the context." and flagged my question as "too broad". I asked myself whether the given quotation could count as a valid close reason by any measure whatsoever. I'm not asking this question to you, as it would be probably count as "too broad".

Instead, I ask what the definition of "a problem the community faces", with or without a context, could be? I [have not found it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+problem+the+community+faces%22+site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com) anywhere in the help section, and I don't see that it would relate to closing questions in general.

Comment: Why would the help section list 'problems that the community faces'? Besides, the 'too broad' reason doesn't fit in your opinion, and although it can be twisted to fit the meaning, I wouldn't close that question as 'too broad' either. But I'm also not too fond of questions that aren't likely to be a productive use of anyone's time, and if I stumbled upon your question earlier, I would have closed it as it doesn't seek productive discussion. Note that, as others have stated, tone plays an important role, and the assumptions made early in the question don't set the tone right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do our questions have to be about actual problems that we face?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124904/do-our-questions-have-to-be-about-actual-problems-that-we-face)

Answer (score 14):

Meta Stack Exchange, and any meta site of Stack Exchange for that matter, is meant for three main things:

1. Report bugs
2. Ask for new features
3. Discuss relevant things related to the site/network

If something doesn't qualify for one of the above, it's likely off topic.

In your specific case, [Is there a habit to downvote new users by default?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326785/is-there-a-habit-to-downvote-new-users-by-default) appears to be part of #3 as it try to discuss voting patterns, **but** it's asked in the wrong way. It's based on wrong assumption that "New users are always downvoted", which prevents any chance for a good discussion.

As far as I can tell, that's the reason for the downvotes, and closure.

Comment: First, thanks, Second, I never meant "New users are always downvoted" to be an assumption. I clarified it now. On the contrary, it was a question, and I made it mathematically precise.

Comment: @user49915  It's more about the tone of the question, not really about the exact words being used.

Comment: You forgot support - ask for help using the site or understanding its features.