# When are "why" questions okay?

Tags: discussion

I have had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736848/why-does-the-linux-kernel-not-perform-field-splitting-on-shebang-lines/) question closed as primarily opinion-based.

Can someone help explain why this question is a bad subjective question? Is it because "why" questions are off-topic? I am confused on this matter.

Comment: Well, it's not really a specific programming problem, I suppose (although asking about workarounds might be).  It might be non-opinion based, though, if someone cited a reference on a mailing list that explained who made that particular decision and why.

Comment: Related: [Is there a rule of thumb for objective questions asked out of curiosity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/162704)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is off-topic because it does not have an objective answer without consulting the creators of Linux. It's not quite a technical question, because it can't be answered by anyone except Torvalds himself (and maybe a few other people)

It's also not particularly about programming, because it doesn't have specific code to point to. It may be more on-topic on programmers, but I'm not sure if it would be very on topic there either

A good "why" question would be one that asks about things like performance, e.g. "Why is A faster than B". Questions like that have an objective answer, because there are measurable things that cause the difference between A's speed and B's speed.

A couple of good examples of "why" questions that can be answered are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array).

Essentially anything that can have an answer that can be contained in a single answer that is 100% correct objectively