# Looking for subjective answers to my questions

Tags: feature-request, subjective

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should we have a subjective version of every stackexchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/should-we-have-a-subjective-version-of-every-stackexchange-site)

I am almost convinced that voting guillotine will cut off my head for this question, but nevertheless I ask it. :-)

Understand that here are preferred questions for that it is possible to give a clear and objective answer. But during my two months on the SO I saw several questions (included asked by me) what has no objective answer.

Anyway, i'm interested for the answers. Where to ask = what is better = type questions? I really want know for example what is better: "dancer" or "mojo" (in perl for example).

And **not want** objective answer - I want reading thru up to 100 different opinions what are upvoted or downvoted by others to see what is good or bad. Will decide myself - **but others opinions and experiences are important for me** - I want learn from others experience, knowledge a wisdom.

So here are possible suggestions:

- make another domain, e.g. subj.stackoverflow.com (like meta) for the subjective questions, and flag/move here all questions what are subjective, open ended or soo.
- make a one special TAG what will be mandatory for opinion/subjective based questions.
- or (the easiest) stop closing questions for which users **want subjective answers**.

**I love SO**. But honestly, I will never understand that why SO silences the subjective views and allows only factual answers.

Excuse me in advance for my last sentence: But, now SO is like communism. No discussion, opinions and subjective though are allowed. Please, take this with a sense of humor. ;)

But...

Comment: If those kind of questions were welcomed in the first place, you wouldn't love SO at all.

Comment: The SO format doesn't work well for subjective questions, __at all__.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I love SO. But honestly, I will never understand that why SO silences the subjective views and allows only factual answers.

Because we have a simple goal:  **Increase the signal-to-noise ratio on the Internet.**  If any kind of discussion were allowed, we'd get a lot more noise.

If you can follow the six *Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions* outlined on [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), your questions are much less likely to be closed on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

It's because subjective answers get out of hand and no definitive answer can really be made. There are a number of different SE sites that you can find by going to Area51.StackExchange.com, which may suit your needs better than SO if you find that you are not getting the assistance that you need. However, asking a concrete question and wanting to receive a concrete answer is really the point of the SO site.

Comment: @jm666: can you post your question in particular that you are having problems with?