# Where should I ask questions about worst practices in language/framework X?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

Yesterday someone asked a question about top bad practices in PHP. It was closed as subjective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php

Was it just wording, and question titled "Most common bad practices in PHP" is OK? Or it's just better to place such questions to other stackexchange site (programmers.stackexchange.com, I guess)?

Comment: I vote those type of questions belong in blog posts after heady levels of research ... remember when you could answer an SO question entirely in monospace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, a 'list of' question ends up doing more harm than good (I'm speaking regarding Stack Overflow). There are *good* [subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), but lists don't usually fall into that category.

We want to encourage people to ask clear technical questions that have technically correct answers in most cases. If a new user sees a 'list of' question and the up votes that it received, they might be inclined to ask a similar question for another language.

List of questions also tend to become flypaper for 'thank you' answers, spam bots and other stuff that moderators have to deal with. Additionally, 'list of' questions tend to attract many duplicate answers.

Programmers SE was founded to provide a venue for people to ask intelligent and engaging subjective questions that garner intelligent and protracted answers, but 'list of' questions are no less problematic there, even though they are generally accepted if written well.

With that said, there is [some usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) to 'list of' questions, but the scope for that is quite narrow.

Answer (score 2):

"Worst practices" questions will rile up more emotion than "best practices" ones.

They are at best subjective right out of the gate, and at worst nearly guaranteed to be argumentative.

Which is to say, "You shouldn't."

Answer (score 0):

You can try programmers, but I'm guessing it won't last long there either. Vote [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: You're right - it won't last long. If nothing else it's a duplicate.