# Posting to share knowledge instead of a strict Q&A

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I have a post that I made to share with others my experience of app submission to the iOS App Store. I don't know what I should do except post a question and answer it myself. I don't know how to move it to any other appropriate spot than Questions, and I keep getting down votes, because technically it is not a question. Instead, it's some experience I considered valuable to share with others.

So what I should do about this?

---

What happened after I post this question here yesterday:

After I post the question here, I drawn some attentions to my original post on Stack overflow,  and got a lot of down votes. I understand that it was not a real question. I mentioned it is not a Q&A and even vote for closing the question myself, however I still got a lot of down votes. Then what happened is the system banned me from asking questions again...

Now I am in the big trouble.

Comment: Can you form it into a question at all? If it really is just experiences, it sounds a bit open-ended

Comment: It is more like the simple fact. It is a hidden rule Apple doesn't document anywhere but actually exist for their app approval.

Comment: If there's a hidden rule, can you form a solid question around it?

Comment: Of course I can make a question out of it, and that's what I did. However I still wonder if there is a better place for the post to go so that it could be easier for others to access.

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000189/rate-your-ios-app-properly-before-send-to-apple-not-qa), @simchona. It's barely on-topic IMO, app store policies aren't programming problems.

Comment: It is OK if you answer your own questions, but you should phrase the question as a question, then post the answer.

Comment: Well, there are still [the blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs), maybe they want it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Answer (score 9):

It's a good thought of yours to share [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000189/rate-your-ios-app-properly-before-send-to-apple-not-qa), but it doesn't quite fit in here on SO. It's hard to see how anyone is going to find it without having already encountered the same difficulty, by which time they have *all* the information. In other words, there's no answer to go looking for.

I spent a few minutes trying to figure out how to rephrase this as a true question/answer pair, but that's the conclusion that I came to -- there is no question here, because the "question" and the "answer" have exactly the same content.

I hope that this doesn't discourage you in general from sharing information or self-answering. This particular tidbit just doesn't seem to have a home on SO.

Perhaps there is a "Pitfalls of the App Store" wiki or blog post somewhere on the wider web that you could add this to?

Comment: Haha, that's exactly what I mean. I don't wanna twist it into a question because really it's not. Thanks for the advice and I will take a look at the wiki see if there is a better place to go.

Comment: "Apple just denied my app on the App Store, claiming that it wasn't reflecting the proper rating because of its cost.  What rating to I need to use to get them to accept a $100+ app?"

Comment: @saluce: Sure it can be re-phrased, but (according to the question), Apple _also_ provided the answer -- 17+ rating is required -- in the same breath. So anyone encountering the issue already has the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is understandable that one wants to pour down his brain once he has solved something.

If you cannot form a question for the problem you have solved, an alternate is to create a blog and keep posting there. Good problem solvers will generally google for their problems and then ask a [good](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) question, if they still can't solve their problem. An already written document that one can refer to makes it much easier for a questioner to be specific.

While doing that you can keep following questions on Stack Overflow to see if there are questions related to what you have blogged already. You can point to these blogs in your answers.

OR people can quote your blog in their questions when they follow your blog but still face a problem, and you can answer those specific questions here. So, the blog indirectly helps in asking better questions also.

Comment: "Pour down one's brain" is a really neat phrase -- is that a translation of an idiom from another language?

Comment: :) No, haven't heard from anyone. I have felt like that many times, myself and use that in my own language some times with my team.

Comment: All right, I'll credit you if I use it myself!

Comment: This seems to indicate that answering your own questions is somehow bad, when actually the opposite is true. If it were there wouldn't be a [UI for it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ldV6t.png),  [a blog.se post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) or [plenty of examples where this was done effectively](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75162/good-self-answers)

Comment: I know about self questioning and answering. This was suggested for a case when one cannot form a good question.

Comment: @OzairKafray perhaps I misread your post but that distinction doesn't appear in your answer.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Yeah, I realized that upon reviewing my answer based on your comment again, and I have added the clarification.