# Where do I put information if I don't have an actual question?

Tags: discussion, questions, article

I've been working with two frameworks for asp.net the last 7 months and the information on combining the two are rather sparse (Despite their growing popularity). I realize I could write a blog post, but I want to share my information with this community. How would i do that if I don't have an actual question?

Comment: Closely related: [Posting to share knowledge instead of a strict Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139415) Basically, just fabricate a question.

Comment: Obvious question: "What steps are necessary when combining `<framework A>` and `<framework B>`?", then self-answer.