# Where opinions run free

Tags: discussion, subjective, subjective-warning

I have seen a number of users get away with opinion based questions on SO. These questions end up closed or put on hold, but they still garner dozens of great, informative answers. I have tried a few time to ask opinion based questions, because I want to draw from the collective experience of the Stack. Sure enough though, these questions get shot down almost immediately. "This is really subjective..." or "Try to make this a yes or no question" is worse then no comment at all. Recently I posted a question on SO. Yes, it was subjective, but I wanted the audience of SO. The audience said it was too subjective, and it should be asked on Programers. The only problem there is, that the people of Programers also said it was too subjective. So, when I do want to gather thoughts from a wealth of experienced programers, with an audience as big as SO, outside of the StackExchange of course, where should I go?

Comment: *Yes, it was subjective, but I wanted the audience of SO*. Please, **don't**. You only manage to anger said audience.

Comment: Stack Exchange is valuable *because* we keep it focused. Subjective questions are off-topic *for a reason*.

Comment: Try slant.co instead. See http://blog.slant.co/post/42487997802/tired-of-being-told-you-aren-t-constructive

Comment: I've noticed that questions that are clear and have proper grammar are received better by the community, even if they are subjective. "In every class, and every book I have seen reguarding programming, classes are held off." is extremely confusing - a class as in something a teacher teaches or a class in OOP? You use both interchangeably.

Comment: `I have seen a number of users get away with opinion based questions on SO. These questions end up closed or put on hold, but they still garner dozens of great, informative answers.` Depending on the age of the questions, they may have been asked at a time when such questions ***were*** acceptable.  So it might not be that they got away with anything, but were simply complying with the rules of the time.

Comment: Lots of downvotes... but the underlying question is "Since I can't ask subjective questions on SO, where can I take them instead?" That's a fair question, helps to keep the site clean. (Even if, ironically, the question is itself subjective).

Comment: @S.L.Barth The underlying question is asking for a site referral outside of SE, which I think is off-topic and could explain the downvotes.  Although how the question is phrased is probably more likely to blame.

Comment: I've noticed some useful questions like [this one from 2 years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read/1713#1713) or [this one from a year ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  They're subjective, but got a lot of upvotes and useful answers.  Why can't we allow this, either on Stack Overflow or a separate Area 51 proposal?

Comment: @BLaZuRE Subjective.SO has been proposed on A51 quite a few times, and each time Stack Exchange said no. And I don't blame them, they are in the laser sharp focused Q&A business, not in the forum business, they want to do one thing and be great at it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @BLA How is that useful? If you want a list of highly-recommended books, you could just go to Amazon. They'll even sell them to you at the same time.

Comment: see also: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to http://slant.co. They are specifically set up to handle subjective questions.

Quoting from 
[Tired of being told you aren’t constructive?](http://blog.slant.co/post/42487997802/tired-of-being-told-you-aren-t-constructive):

> Given our own experiences and the popularity of closed StackOverflow questions, we’re sure we are not alone in wanting a solution to help us quickly pick between competing approaches, products, and services. So we built it.