# Where can I ask questions about good plugins or other solutions?

Tags: discussion

I've asked the same question here (I had not read the rules, sorry, I assumed this was more for general discussion.) and on the regular SO site, and both times the question was closed. "Don't ask about anything that is related to opinion" is pretty much what I've got from that.

The answer to this question: [What can we do about questions asking for plugin/script recommendations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94132/what-can-we-do-about-questions-asking-for-plugin-script-recommendations) doesn't answer the "where" portion of what I'm asking.

The answer to this question lists a lot of forums (or a link to the list anyway) but is not relevant to the question I have, and the answers are much slower coming in. One of my favorite things about SO is how quickly people answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow

I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: `One of my favorite things about SO is how quickly people answer` one of the reasons people answer so quickly and so well is that the site is free of opinion-based questions.

Comment: While it's not really SO's job to recommend other sites, some suggest slant.co (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191417/where-opinions-run-free))

Comment: @DavidRobinson I have seen at least half a dozen questions similar to the one I'm asking, asking for the same type of "opinionated" answers, that were answered and in some cases up voted. The problem is they're all quite old and not relevant. In my question I asked what a good plugin would be for a problem, and listed about 10 that I had either tried, or that I had found in other questions that were no longer valid.

Comment: @Jack: Again, the reason they received many upvotes is that they're old. StackOverflow used to have different standards for recommendation questions, and their poor experience with such questions is what led to the rules against them. I'm guessing most of the ones you've seen are closed: and if not, if you provide a link I'm sure they soon will be.

Comment: @Jack: Note that many such questions, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript), even have a lock and a message explaining this: `This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here`

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'm sorry, but I thought the biggest difference in my question, which I know you cannot see, and other "what's a good tool" questions is the sheer number of things that I had already tried. It severely narrows down what the answer could be if you already tried what is in a lot of answers to similar questions. But that's just my two cents. Good point on the old question thing though.