# Why Such discouraging and limiting policies for opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I have observed several times, whenever I ask something that relates or compares two things, moderator puts it on hold saying that it will invite chatty discussion.

But why are there such policies? Sometimes, questions are so genuine and unique that very rare or no attention is previously concentrated. But just because they compare two things they are put on hold.

A very recent incident is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882080/java-support-for-multi-core-processing-vs-openmp-posix. This question is very genuine and almost rarely concentrated before. But just because it compares Java and OpenMP, it is put on hold. And I observed this mostly happens when Java is compared with some other technology. I suspect sometimes Stack Exchange is biased towards Java and it really doesn't allow to find pitfalls in it.

Doing this I think Stack Exchange discourages people from asking questions. Instead why don't you dedicate one site to such questions?

Being a leading technology forum, I never expected this from Stack Exchange. And I must admit that Stack Exchange is limiting its scope of exploring various technologies and their interdependency, superiority comparisons etc.

If Stack Exchange isn't built for such questions, then where should we post such questions? Because I don't find any other discussion forum as robust and complete as Stack Exchange.

Comment: It was put on hold by the community, not by a moderator (a moderator has a diamond next to their name).  Also, Stack Exchange consists of Q&A sites, *not* forums.  The objective is to post concrete questions and receive concrete answers, *not* hold discussions.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191419/194698

Comment: `Because I don't find any other discussion forum so robust and complete as StackExchange.` That's the reason opinion-based question aren't allowed on SE: to avoid becoming one of those week and uncomplete fora

Comment: @Jamal Whoever. I am not interested in knowing people hierarchy. And I  don't at all think that question was inviting a chatty discussion. It was concrete and I know experienced people are there who can provide concrete answer to it. But just because your way of applying filter is a limiting matter of discouraging such question.

Comment: If there are people who disagree with the closure, then they will cast reopen votes.  Nonetheless, the community has spoken.

Comment: Somebody has recently commented that http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the correct site to ask such question, then why didn't you migrate the said question to that site if it wasn't asked on right stackexchange. Such activities are really strange & disgusting sometimes.

Comment: I don't see how this is "strange & disgusting."  Have you considered flagging for moderator attention?  They may be able to locate the correct site (if any) and migrate it for you.  As that is a beta site thus not a possible migration path, the community was unable to do it themselves.

Comment: @DamienPirsy So then tell me where should I post such questions. Because I am very much hungry to know answers.

Comment: I think your question is salvageable if you rephrase it so that it doesn't look like you want a comparison, but rather "how would you achieve the same thing in Java"

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. After long I got such nice advice :) Otherwise I was engaged in a long series of arguments with community members and moderator.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: @Jamal I've modified the said [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882080/how-user-level-thread-library-of-java-supports-multi-core-processing). It is more concrete now. And wouldn't invite chatty discussion. Will you please release the on-hold filter now?

Comment: It's funny how this very question (which I voted up, as I often wondered the same myself) was down-voted to the point of perhaps almost being itself put on hold (ironically).

Answer (score 11):

Polling / opinion based questions were determined to be a poor fit for the StackExchange Q&A format - rather than inviting an arguably "correct" answer, they would attract many varying opinions, discussions, spam, etc.

There was a conscious decision by the community a while ago that this result was not desired, so this type of question is discouraged.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/194698) has much more in depth details behind this issue.

If you can reframe your question in a way that makes it have an answer rather than just a collection of opinions, that is probably the best way.  Another option would be to take this type of question to another site with a community that encourages opinions and discussion.  [Here's one suggested in another answer about where to ask opinion based questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191419/194698)

Comment: As a note, I'm sure I've seen a similar answer to this kind of question before, so I'm paraphrasing it from (a rather sleepy) memory, but my search-fu skills are failing me right now, otherwise I'd link to it...

Comment: I re-framed my question the way you suggested. But the On-hold filter isn't yet removed. I don't understand, when you apply on-hold filter, you make a quick consensus among community member, but when it comes to releasing that filter, you say, you have to earn at least 5 up-votes. Why such un-fairness?

Comment: Both closing and reopening take 5 votes - what exactly is unfair?

Comment: I never saw 5-down votes on my post before it is put on-hold. If its an internal matter, but why it is hidden?

Comment: Even above post got 8 down votes, why it is not put on-hold then?

Comment: [Close/reopen](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) votes are moderation related tools, and are different than the more visible [up/down votes on questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).  I strongly recommend reading through the [help center topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to get a better understanding of how SO works, especially the part about [how questions get reopened](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). If you still have more questions about how the site works (that isn't already answered), ask another question on meta.