# Where to post a question on machine learning web-service implementation

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried to post the question below on Stack Overflow, then on Cross Validated, then on Server Fault but my question has been stated as off-topic each time. I'm a bit fed up because I have posted far more answers than questions on Stack Overflow and the day I need some help: no way. I always asked how could I make this question not off-topic or where would it be better to post then, but no answer. Just a downvote or on-hold response. I know it is not a programming issue but there are many very, very similar questions on Stack Overflow so I am really surprised. It seems a bit more picky when it relates to questions on R.

> *R web-service for real-time prediction with online learning*
>
> What free framework or R packages should I use to deploy R as a web
>   service handling many models for real-time prediction (with online
>   learning) ?
>
> It should be able to address those key points:
>
> - allow parallel processing/requests while handling a memory/cpu policy preventing reaching memory/cpu limits.
> - update many models in parallel safely (ie. prevent concurrent updates). able to quickly load/unload many models on a single machine
>     because not all models (ie. >1000) could fit in memory.
> - handle large streams with low footprint (out-of-core).
> - able to use VowpalWabbit and StreamMOA R packages.
> - web service could be Http or Thrift based.
>
> Thanks a lot for any help!

**FYI, the different versions of my question:**

- 1st try on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488144/r-for-real-time-prediction-and-online-learning-on-many-models
- CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122748/r-web-service-for-real-time-prediction-with-online-learning
- 2nd try on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775103/r-web-service-for-real-time-prediction-with-online-learning
- Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/642516/r-web-service-for-real-time-prediction-with-online-learning

Comment: Requests for recommendations have been off-topic for a _long_ time. It's surprising to me that you wouldn't know that. Further, the close reasons on your not-yet-deleted questions clearly spell that out.

Comment: ...see also: [Searching for software recommendation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199285/searching-for-software-recommendation)

Answer (score 4):

You question (in its present form) is *not fit for any of the present SE sites*.

Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic for both [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) also has very specific requirements for recommendation questions in order to maintain it's quality, as mentioned in [their questions guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336), and your question doesn't fit these criteria.

As per [the tag wiki of machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) on Stack Overflow:

> **NOTE:** If you want to use this tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
>   or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead. Otherwise you're probably off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

The only site that allows questions asking for software recommendations is the aptly named [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

There is also a [Code Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations) site proposal that would be a "Q&A site for programmers seeking the best library for specific tasks."  But that site is still in the definition stage and won't take actual questions until it makes it to the beta phase (if it makes it).

Comment: Ok, I'll try there then. However I still think downvoting and off-topic could be really improved to avoid mimetism (ie. I could get some upvotes on a question and once someone start to say it's off-topic, you're nearly dead. It scares others who back off). There are also some expert happy downvoters, just compare some profiles stats.