# Off topic and now deleted, with no feedback on how to improve

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

This is in reference to [my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466179/best-lightweight-restful-framework-for-php-5-3?noredirect=1#comment29653330_3466179); I am willing to change the question such that it is complying with the requirements / rules; despite asking for comments on my edits to remove the off-topic flag, no one had the time to respond to that, but had the time to request delete.

That's not a very good community spirit, IMO. I would love to edit it and make it better, so that the question can be helpful, as it has bee to a fair few people who has been looking for answers to a similar question.

What are my options? or more precisely, how can I preserve that question and answer thread.

---

As suggested by @MikePennington, if I am given a chance, I would like to edit the question to look as below.

> **Choosing a lightweight RESTful framework for PHP 5.3**
>
> My experience with PHP frameworks is Kohana 2.x; I have been using it to develop RESTful APIs. The one thing I feel quite out of place with using Kohana for the purpose is, it does not feel natural to write RESTful APIs with it; the MVC feels like a hurdle in the way to the "resource". What I have seen so far is people stressing ubiquitously and inappropriately, on the MVC pattern when they talk about frameworks. I have also seen people taking unnecessary pain and struggle to fit everything into MVC; that definitely doesn't feel right!
>
> I am trying to make sure that my criteria (below) is appropriate, for selecting a PHP framework for the purpose of creating RESTful APIs.
>
> - One that models resources ( for RESTful-ness )
> - Object oriented ( not just for the sake of it )
> - Not one that forces to use MVC
> - No unnecessary fat ( strange database layers and ORMs )
> - Pay for what I use ( nothing is automatic, but gives me means to make them automated )
> - Sensible logging ( unlike kohana )
> - Sensible configuration ( unlike kohana, not every techie is a PHP programmer )
>
> If I have missed any criteria, or any of my criteria needs to be reviewed, please leave a note. It would be wonderful if you could, in amongst the discussion, share your choice of PHP framework, with their pros and cons.

Comment: TBH I don't think you will ever be able to edit it to make it *on topic*. *However*, it *is* useful to the community (27k views over it's lifetime), so I would like to see it undeleted and a historical lock put on it (which you'll have to wait for a moderator to do).

Comment: Just because it's viewed often doesn't automatically make it a good or useful question. It could just be a question many people ask themselves, but they still might not find good answers here (or too many, etc.). Note: I haven't seen your question, but judging from the title it's something that should be absolutely discouraged these days, so there's really not a point in keeping it around.

Comment: For reference: [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: 27k really isn't *that* much in three years time @Matt

Comment: @codemedic as one of the people who tries to cleans up the PHP tag and delete-voted your question I just want to say that it will be *very* hard if not just impossible to edit that question into something more on-topic on the site. Even after your edit it is still asking for a shopping list which is off topic.

Comment: @PeeHaa: It would be the [second-highest viewed question posted that month](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150475/most-viewed-questions-created-within-2-dates?StartDate=08%2F01%2F2010&EndDate=08%2F31%2F2010) (Data.SE times out if I select a wider range :(), so I disagree that 27k *isn't that much*.

Comment: @PeeHaa: ... and within the top 20 questions posted between 01/01/2010 and 31/08/2010.

Comment: Hmmmm. I just looked at my answers and it didn't seem too much. Fair enough.

Comment: @Matt you seem to confuse the urge for people to reaffirm, that their choice of framework has been the right one, with question actually being useful & fit for SO.

Comment: @teresko: I'm not confusing a useful question being a good fit for SO. That's what the historical lock is for; the lock message shows up as "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.", which is exactly what this situation is. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: @Matt by which criteria it is "stellar"? And it does not have any historical significance, because it is "name your favorite framework" post, which mean that aside from being unfit for SO, it also will rot with time.

Comment: @Matt: There aren't 31 months in the year, silly.

Comment: @teresko: In all honestly, until now I had merely skimmed the question and answers; I agree it shouldn't be classified as *stellar*, but still think the *27,000* views should count for something. The question is doing no harm being closed. The "This question is closed due to it being...* should be enough to let people know those type of questions are *no-longer* suitable on SE sites.

Comment: @Won't: I know right. Damn you Americans.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly, you're asking for a resource recommendation, quoting your last edit:

> Please can you suggest any really lightweight PHP framework, tuned towards writing RESTful frameworks around APIs; one that assumes its users to be capable of making the judgement judgment

Stack Exchange strives to be an [authoritative resource for Questions and Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75940/160519).  Polls and recommendations wind up being a [Compilation of knowledge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/997/handling-game-recommendations-how-can-we-solve-these-two-problems-of-quality), which are fundamentally at odds with the structure of [SE](https://stackexchange.com/).  In short, the question as-phrased is off-topic.

[Sometimes you can rephrase a recommendation request to be something on-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/77053) by rephrasing the question as looking for a set of criteria to help select the resource.

As someone mentioned in the comments, [SE](https://stackexchange.com/) sometimes keeps questions with historical value around, but increasingly it seems like I see more and more of those getting deleted.  While it might feel like a slap in the face to have the question deleted, at least you walked away with some [bling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=83005)

Comment: Spot on ... "Sometimes you can rephrase a recommendation request to be something on-topic by rephrasing the question as looking for a set of criteria to help select the resource." thats what I have been after; a guide to make the question more compliant! Especially with PHP and frameworks, it is a constantly changing playground. I would love to be able to do that, but too late I guess! Any idea what would happen to the reputation that I amassed (and lost by downvotes) via that question?

Comment: @CodeMedic, please go ahead and revise your question again.  When you've done so, update your [meta] question with the new information.  At that point, the community could look at reopening.  As for reputation, that goes away when the question is deleted.  If the question is reopened, obviously you'd get the rep back.  That said, ~150 points isn't real hard to come by on [so]... you could also answer some more questions if you want the points.

Comment: oh! my 150 points ... no just kidding ... you are right! First deleted question for me, so was just curious. I have posted an edited version on the question above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, **framework beauty pageants are off-topic**. What you have there is a dictionary-example of one. And the result of that awful question is exactly what one would expect.

> I am willing to change the question such that it is complying with the requirements / rules; despite asking for comments on my edits to remove the off-topic flag, no one had the time to respond to that, but had the time to request delete.

And this argument is completely **invalid**. The reason for closing was clearly stated:

> "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

You had one and a half month to use Google Translate to decipher this description. Beside, the only reason why you are even posting this is to cry about the lose of 150 points and not because you genuinely think that the question is a benefit to SO community.

**P.S.** Even if you somehow managed to change the question, **what will you do with answers?**

Comment: While I don't disagree much with this, I think the tone is a little much, especially the P.S.  A language barrier would not appear to be the issue.

Comment: 150 points is not that big a deal; the point is I have found it hard to find a "good" answer to the/my problem mentioned in the question. One could find a lot of comparison charts of PHP frameworks, but most of them are biased towards the very thing I was against; the MVC one-size-fits-all-approach aspect!

Comment: Your problem (from what I gathered) was "implementing RESTful API in Kohana seems forced and/or arbitrary". But you were not asking for solutions to solve it. Instead you were looking for a list of framework. Even now you seem to imply that only way you can even imagine to solve it is by comparing frameworks.

Comment: I have gone to various lengths to get around my problem. I have tried implementing my own ( from scratch ) PHP framework which has been working satisfactorily in production environment. But that is not the point, not every project / company / programmer has the luxury of roll your own frameworks. Even that point aside, if someone is setting out to write a framework for their own purpose, it will be nice to have a well rounded (unbiased) feel of what is already out there, who want to reinvent the wheel, unless it the new wheel (of course) is not round in shape and it has a billion benefits!

Comment: For some reason you think, that only way to solve your problem, is to start with step which says "have a framework". Wa-wa-why ?!

Comment: "PHP Frameworks" .. that probably should be read as "enabling PHP library" ... No matter what you think about it, it definitely helps people working on a project to talk the same language! It also does enable continuous improvement to the product ( or most likely products ) in an centralised fashion! Thats what I have experienced over my piddly little working life!