# What SE site allows to ask opinions and ideas

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange

Is SO the right place to ask something like this?

"I would like to get some workarounds on how to edit, delete then adjust data numbering from access" - well in a more detailed way of course.

Or is there a proper SE site for this type?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383)