# Are theoretical questions about programming acceptable that aren't as deep as cstheory?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Last night there was a question on Stack Overflow: [Is it theoretically possible to write a java machine with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21745831/369450) It was subsequently put on hold for being too broad of a question.

To me, this is a very simple question with a simple answer: yes it is possible, but it would  not be a trivial task. The OP did not ask specifics about how to implement it, so it's probably not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

The CS Theory site might be a little overboard for this question because if he wanted to know whether PHP was *Turing complete*, he could ask (or get migrated) there. Would the Programmers SE be appropriate for this sort of question? Or is there any other Stack Exchange site where this sort of question would be applicable?

Comment: And what would be a purpose of questions like that, at all? Why would we need any place for them? Also, related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Is that sort of question valid anywhere or is not relevant to *stackexchange*?

Comment: If its turing complete then the answer must be yes. The only value must be in the detail which would be very broad

Comment: I think your question is not really well written. It looks like you assume there is / should be a place for them. And the linked question is not a shallow theoretical one, it's more like broad practical one. If it would go like "what conditions must language meet, to write interpreter / VM of language Y in it?" or something, it still would be broad, but at least really theoretical, with some possibility to actually be useful for someone.

Comment: @Mołot I am making no assumption that this sort of question *should* or *should not* be allowed. I'm curious *if* it is allowed. If so, *where*? If not, *that's what I wanted to know*.

Comment: @cpburnz title of your question clearly states "where", not "are they" ;)

Comment: @Mołot Perhaps the body of the question conflicted with the title. I'll amend it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two potential ways to answer such a question

> yes it is possible, but it would not be a trivial task.

or

> yes it is possible, it can be done in the following way ....

The first way is a terrible answer, are we supposed to just take their word for it?! There could just as easily be an answer saying "no" and then the voting becomes a straw poll on peoples "reckonings" as to if it can be done.

The second way is more useful, but it would be insanely broad, hence the closure. As such I don't think this question would be acceptable anywhere.

If you were to instead ask a questions on [turing completeness](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turing-completeness) then it appears to be well received on programmers. So it may be possible to ask a question regarding if PHP is turing complete, if it is then you can infer that any programming task is technically possible. Since turing completeness has a small number of well defined tests this is actually a less broad question.

Comment: I should note that they are on topic, if a question is Too Broad for SO (for the reasons you described), it would likely also get the same reception on P.SE.  The question of if/why php is Turing complete is rather boring of a question as the answer is "yes it is, here's a Turing machine simulator written in php, therefore its complete. https://gist.github.com/igorw/6984880 " or it might get closed as a dup of [What makes a language Turing-complete?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132385/what-makes-a-language-turing-complete)