# Problem with disallowing Poll-based questions

Tags: discussion

As I understand it, the reason that poll-based questions are disallowed on Stackoverflow is because they lend themselves poorly to the Q&A format.

Several explanations for this exist on meta, but I found tzenes answer to this question to be the most helpful:

[Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

The problem I see is that Stackoverflow has become too powerful and dominant in the community for this policy. It is no longer "just a Q&A site". It is the best site, by a huge margin, to glean wisdom from the community in general.

Because of this, for problems that lend themselves to poll-based questions (Example: What software library should I try for X?), even though it was not designed for this purpose, it is still THE best place to get this type of information. And despite its being a poor format for poll-based questions. There is no legitimate competitor.

(Here is an example of a great source of information from a Stackoverflow poll-based question: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags))

If I understand correctly, an ideal solution to this problem would be to implement a system that works better for poll based questions. I mean who wouldn't want to know that "X" software package is liked by the most people with the highest reputation?

Unfortunately, it takes time and money to implement new software. So in the mean time, I might suggest one or more of these temporary solutions:

- Allow poll-based questions, but have them tagged as "poll" so people can easily filter them out.
- By moderator discretion, stop closing poll-based questions with significant up-votes
- By moderator discretion, opt to not close poll-based questions from users with high reputation or who have obviously put a lot of time into crafting a well-worded question
- Only allow poll-based questions and answers from users with significantly high reputation.

Comment: I would completely disagree that your example is a great source of information. The top answer there is a list of links. I know that if I was searching for something on Google and came across that, I would be **incredibly frustrated** that I just got walled with a bunch of links with absolutely no description of what each one does, which is better, what they look like. I'd have to click through to each one individually, blindly even, and try to figure out which one is closest to my needs. That's just plain not useful in my eyes. If I encountered that on a hunt, I'd swiftly close the page.

Comment: @animuson - I see what you are saying, but a better alternative is not immediately obvious to me. What would your strategy be to finding the best library?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow: I'd gather criteria and then evaluate libraries found through a thorough Google search coupled with a documentation and code evaluation to see how well they fit the criteria. E.g. do my research and make a pick. Your criteria will almost certainly differ from mine though, so my pick won't be helpful to you. Nor will it be helpful to you *6 months from now*.

Comment: The *Stack Overflow is now popular* argument does not fly at all; Stack Overflow is popular **because** we keep poll questions out. The site is popular because the community is bullish about quality, and experience has shown that polls lead to low-quality results. Now that the site is so popular that counts more than ever as more and more people come to the site not only to find the information but to also participate. More people on polls means lower quality still.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow I have to agree with you wholeheartedly here Chris. There are some so called "poll questions" that aren't actually such. For example, there is a **BIG** difference between asking "Which is the **best** resource?" and "What is/are a/some **good** resources?". The former is opinion-based, poll-style, and unconstructive. The latter is not, and lends itself well to constructive suggestions. I think this is the type Chris is pushing for. An admin who **closes** such posts because he/she thinks they are "unconstructive" is being just as pollish as people who **ask** the former type.

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly always an interesting matter when it comes up. I certainly agree that SE (and in particular, SO) has managed to place itself in a unique position at the intersection of good questions and good answers, so it's an awesome place to learn from experts. And by nature, experts tend to have relatively strong opinions on things.

But that said, I still have to respectfully disagree with your proposal to promote polling questions on *most* sites.

Before I get too much into why, I'll just throw out there two sites that deserve particular mention here.

- [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) isn't meant explicitly for lists of software, but it does accomplish much of what you're trying for.
- [Code Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations) is still in definition on Area51, but if it makes it to beta, it will be somewhat similar to SR, but for libraries.

But back to my point, I think there are a couple problems with opinion-based questions like this. Those sites get around these issues in that they can *typically* be self-contained (answers are provable, via features of recommended software, for instance).

I'll just throw this one in here to get it over with, because it has to be said at some point. Questions that seek discussion are notoriously good at attracting spam, and spam introduces [broken windows](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/) that snowball. That's probably not a particularly *interesting* reason, but it's a reason.

Beyond that, though, opinion-based questions introduce discussions, and a pretty big part of the goal behind Stack Exchange is to avoid discussion. Have a programming question? Pop on SO, find your question, see the answer, be gone. That's the goal. A simple, content-centric source for expert opinions that are based on measurable and indisputable fact. When discussion starts coming in, it becomes a game of who's-who, and suddenly people become more important than posts.

If your question is "should I do this or that?," and there are no factual basics off of which to base an answer, the points will go to the user with the highest rep. People will agree with a user like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) whether he's right or not (I mean no disrespect to Jon, he certainly tends to be right), because nobody can prove anything over anything else. That's probably fine in practice, but that's not what SE is about, nor is it what SE *wants to be about.*

That becomes an issue in your "Only allow poll-based questions and answers from users with significantly high reputation" idea, too. It becomes a game for users with a certain rep, and not for the community on the whole.

You'll notice that currently, reputational privileges show knowledge on the site. Have you been around for a little while? Now you understand what voting is, so we'll let you. Do you recognize what makes a good edit? Now you don't need supervision. By opening up to users only being able to provide content of certain types, we'd be breaking that trend in the interest of filtering content based on previous content, and that's just not what Stack Exchange is about.

So at the end of the day, I don't necessarily think that polling questions wouldn't work here, but I *do* think that they'd undermine much of what's been done to keep SE fair and productive, and they'd work in opposition to some of the fundamental philosophies that SE has tried to build off of. Not allowing polls is a central conceit of the "we are not a forum" philosophy, which is probably much of what's brought SE to be so prevalent.

Not to mention, remember that the examples you see are the good ones. For any productive polling question you come across, know that mods have probably deleted a ton of bad ones.

Comment: +1 - It sounds like what you are saying is that the negative side of polling would outweigh the positive. While I do not agree with this, I certainly believe that its a legitimate view point. I think the only way to argue the point farther would be to examine similar situations where tightening or loosening moderation resulted in positive or negative consequences. I'm not sure if that kind of information is even readily available.

Comment: @Chris It's a little bit of that, and a little bit that I just don't really think it's worth changing a good thing right now, if that makes any sense. I think SR and the code recs proposal account for the aspects of polling that can be done productively, if that makes any sense. But yes, regardless, it's definitely a good idea to revisit every once in a while, and that's why you got a +1 from me as well. :)

Comment: I didn't know about the code recs proposal. I believe this would almost completely solve the problem, especially if moderators were careful to comment on the correct place to post the question when they closed it (or just moved it). As far as the "its not worth changing a good thing" argument. To me this is a very good argument. However, I do seem to be noticing a recent spike in discontent and have personally received more "beat-downs" than normal lately, however this is not based on hard data and could be due to an increase in age and traffic.

Comment: @Chris Yep, user-based migration paths are only allowed for graduated sites, but I'm sure one would be approved to code recs if its beta went well enough. And I know mods (I'm a mod on Startups) tend to try our best to migrate questions rather than just closing them, so even before users were given the option, that channel would become well-used. As for discontent, I think the rules that are in place are there with good reasons, and it's a case of a vocal minority who get their questions closed frequently for this. But I could be way off on that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if its a legitimate amount of users or just a vocal minority. However, I have noticed that the people who wield power on Stackoverflow seem to more often have user experiences significantly weighted towards answering questions as opposed to asking them. What appears as a vocal minority could be a significant amount of people who's skills are weighted more towards the beginner level.

Comment: @Chris my apologies for not responding earlier. In any event, yes, I agree that a majority of high-rep users are answerers, but I also don't totally agree that that's relevant. As a general rule, reputation on Stack Exchange sites is meant as a direct measure of someone's familiarity with the site. It's not 100% effective, but I trust it on the whole. So when high-rep users are up in arms, claiming that polling questions *just won't work,* I weight that opinion more heavily than I'd weight that of someone who just joined the site. And answerers tend to know what makes good answers.

Comment: But regardless, it sounds like Code Recs will likely suffice for what you want. Beyond that and SR, we're only talking about questions like "I'm thinking of writing a library that does this, would that be useful to you?" and that sort, and those are where it becomes a who's-who and it isn't constructive.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen - I have to disagree in general. As I said in my first comment on the OP, there are some so-called "polling-questions" that actually aren't, and *these* are the ones that make people (rightfully) grumpy when an admin closes them. I've had many questions that were answered by exactly such questions in the exact SO spirit you described--*"Come with a question, get a succinct answer, and get back to work"*. I've also come with such questions and been frustrated because the ONE question that might have gotten a good answer for it was poorly closed.