# Regarding the acedemic elitism or 'rule' by small intellectual 'oligarchies' that seems to be present in these sites

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, etiquette

I asked a simple question Science Fiction & Fantasy about why the majority of science fiction stories make references to supernatural or psychic phenomena and the few that responded did seem to disagree or where perturbed about me even asking the question. I wrote many philosophers don't believe in the supernatural. Many scientists probably don't either so why is it mentioned so much in science fiction? There where a few comments then it was closed and then the 'Community' made it so no one can comment any further.

I *personally* (if I had a lot of reputation points) would not vote to close down **any** question (as long as it was not offensive); if a question was vague or badly written I would make suggestions on how to improve it if I could, or to prevent chaos as some user suggested I wouldn't necessarily reply at all (no comment is better than even unintentionally discouraging responses). I was surprised at the sci-fi site some special group could just prevent any more comments. This is not the mark of a free idea sharing website. So, **and this is my question**: why is any special group or individual allowed to filter out any questions they don't appear to like?

Comment: This question itself is not phrased as a question, I guess that's why it's been downvoted?

Comment: Since I couldn't find the question mentioned on the post, I assumed it's deleted? Without seeing the actual question, it might be difficult to judge, but reading from your description, it probably is too opinion-based. Just saying, [se] is not a forum for open discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: Why is this considered off topic? I'm asking why a privileged few or privileged individuals have the right to not only close down a question but also prevent any further discussion or comments on a question. IS THIS APPROPRIATE for web sites that advertise themselves as being open to ANYONE to ask any question on the topics mentioned in the sites? THE INPUT I'M SEEKING is if the people that 'indirectly' control the content of these websites think any type of privileged editing or censorship is a reasonable thing to promote?

Comment: Why do you have a Meta stack exchange if you don't accept certain criticisms?

Comment: Why has this question gotten -18 points?

Comment: -20 now.. on meta, it is an indication that many in the community do not agree with the proposal usually.

Comment: It seems my question about sci-fi stories without psychic events has been censored; taken off the site, this is frustrating. Why is suggesting a minority of sci-fi stories have no mentioned psychic phenomenon an 'illegal' action by the sci-fi web sites standards? And not only preventing further comments but making the question disappear is certainly the actions of a 'special' group or individual controlling the content of the relevant site.

Comment: Agree it's on topic and voted to Reopen, but also agree with the downvotes here, since what you suggest (never close or lock anything) would lead to total chaos. Plus, I don't like being called "elitist".

Comment: @ShadowWizard ; someone told me on these sites I should have a thicker skin; I didn't say everyone should never close down a question or criticise a question as if the author of the question is not worthy. I was only saying what I myself would do. You're assuming I' m suggesting policy changes. I certainly don't think any of my suggestion would be followed. And I 'm only calling the users elitest who use their privaledges to block or close down or make disappear any question they don't like or for other personal or biased reasons. The rules for what questions discarded are not clear.

Comment: It says above 'this question does not appear to seek input and discussion..' Yet in the question it clearly says ,'Why is any special group or individual allowed to filter out any question they don't appear to like..?' This is NOT a rhetorical question. Do other users think all the users on these sites edit , or 'make vanish' any given question with an attitude of totally objective , stoic analysis . Or that no user could be 'biased' against a question? Like I mentioned before I wouldn't have bothered to write any of this had not 3 of my questions on the sic-fi site been quickly destroyed.

Comment: I could always ask the question again on the sci-fi and fantasy s.e. site and see if they delete it quickly or they might block my questions entirely siting problems with my type of questioning which would prove an unfair bias ; since I'VE ONLY ASKED 2 questions on the site..

Comment: I actually asked the question again today and surprise surprise it was closed and deleted in one day , that is today ; I just looked on the site and it indicates in the hidden files the question was closed ,deleted and further comments were blocked. It also says the only way I can comment further is by changing the question. All those 24 voters that disagree with the idea any users with the privaledge of editing can be biased and abuse this privaledge can look up the records of my questions on the sci-fi and fantasy s.e.website, in the hidden files..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I respect your concerns here, but I must say, I've never seen a situation where a very good, on-topic question was closed by members of a community, let alone locked.

It's hard to really tell you anything without being able to see the question we're talking about, but my suspicion is that there's more going on than you're indicating in your question here on meta.

[Questions get locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228) in specific circumstances, primarily when people start off-topic, uncontrollable discussions that don't improve the post.

On the other hand, [questions can also be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221), which sounds more likely for what you're talking about. That can happen in edge-cases where a post is spammy, extremely off-topic or low-quality, or has been closed for some time without being improved.

Comment: I think stack exchange would benefit from a better mechanism or policy to merge extremely similar questions.  In my opinion, that kind of moderation would benefit the site more than the closure of seemingly unhelpful or ill-phrased questions - which quite often can be helpful to a certain audience, and might better be edited rather than closed.

Comment: @Matthew Haugen ; What do you mean 'hard to really tell you anything without being able to see the question..'; I Mentioned I was writing about a question I asked in the sci-fi and fantasy site under 'user 128932' ,about if the amount of sci-fi stories that don't mention psychic phenomena where in the minority.

Comment: @Matthew Haugens; my question was not extremely off topic or low quality or been closed for some time. I simply asked why a minority of sci-fi stories have no mention of psychic phenomena. This seems clear enough. It is not low quality. I mean why do MOST sci-fi stories have psychic events in them? That is a simple question too. Maybe some people at the sci-fi and fantasy s.e. site did not like my question and abused their closing-down and question-disappearing 'abilities'.

Comment: That sounds like a question I would down vote - you are  asking why authors decide to write stories in certain styles? Opinion based in my opinion.

Comment: @Rory Alsop ; no I,m not asking about writing styles. The question I asked is simple , Are the sci-fi stories that don't make reference to  psychic events in the MINORITY. It is not about writing style or opinions, simply how many non-occult mentioning sci-fi stories have been written.

Comment: Somebody on these sites suggested I should get a thicker skin when taking criticisms. I suggest these s.e. sites including the meta s.e. site should adopt a thicker skin when taking criticisms. What is the meta s.e. site for but taking in criticisms and DISCUSSING them not just downvoting them. Why have the downvotes increased. If my question is that offensive why not make it disappear like you people have doneregarding some of my other questions?  Why keep punishing me and my reputation ( unless its personal )?

Comment: That definitely sounds off topic, or possibly too broad then. The simple answer is "Yes", but that's not a helpful answer, and it may change over time. Your question doesn't appear to ask that though. And if you look at how SE works, communities are supposed to up- and down-vote. Any individual with a relatively small amount of rep can do this.

Comment: Oh - and as mentioned higher up, downvotes on meta simply indicate disagreement. They also don't impact your rep.

Comment: Please note that according to your own rules a user with a certain number of reputation points can comment or up or down vote or edit e.t.c., a user with a lot of reputation points can vote to accept or block or close down a question. Such is a privaledged user ; this is part of your own rules. Your problem is you assume any privaledged user or users who are closing down or 'disappearing' a question are doing so for perfectly valid objective reasons. There are no hidden biases in any privaledged users reasons for shutting down a question. I suggest in some cases there are hidden biases.

Comment: NO ONE told me a lot of down votes do not in ANY way have an effect on ones reputation. @Rory Alsop ; thank you for answering my question about sci-fi stories and the occult and this IS what I was asking. I don't know why someone on the sci-fi s.e. site couldn't have said that without closing down the question and forbidding further comment and disappearing the question! And by the way ,I don't know if I have enough privaledges to block or close a question but I  would NEVER close down a question ( if it was not offensive) I would try to make suggestions on IMPROVING a question if I could..

Comment: Rory Alsop answered my question quite simply and succinctly. He said 'my question doesn't appear to ask that' but yes it does. Instead of certain users trying to interpret what I'm asking 'between the lines' or what my 'motivations are for asking a question and closing down a question if they don't like it , they shouldn't let personal bias cause this. I ONLY wrote this complaint because I was shocked at how FAST my question was closed down , any further comments were blocked and then the question was destroyed. All on the Sci-fi s.e. site. This also happened with two other questions I wrote.

Comment: IF Rory Alsop and users like him were at the sci-fi site they might have answered my question quickly without all the second guessing of what are my real motivations for asking the question. And the question itself might nit have been *DESTROYED* so quickly.