# Where to post questions related to configuration management tools?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions related to configuration management tools.

Does Stack Exchange have an appropriate site for such questions, and if so which is it?

By configuration management tool, I'm thinking of Puppet, Ansible, SaltStack, Chef, and Cfengine.

Comment: What kind of configuration?

Comment: Related how exactly? In what aspect? Programming with those tools? Using those tools? Comparing?

Comment: In case you are looking for recommendations of tools, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/201151) thread might be informative for you.

Comment: [sf] would be the closest fit, I think, but it would very much depend on what your actual questions are.