# Where to post Configuration Management related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the proper site to ask questions regarding Configuration Management (CM) including, but not limited to, Software Configuration Management (SCM)?

I scanned meta to see if this had been asked before but only found a question asked about CM tools (which I consider quite different) which was never answered:

[Where to post questions related to configuration management tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257256/where-to-post-questions-related-to-configuration-management-tools)

I would think stack overflow or perhaps programmers would be the most appropriate if the question dealt directly or even indirectly with programming; however there does not seem to be a site for CM processes and general conventions.

Comment: Programmers has a [tag:Configuration management](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration-management)