# Alternatives to point discussion type questions to

Tags: discussion, redirection

I am somewhat new to Stack Exchange, but one thing I have noticed is that the policy of not allowing discussion type questions is a very good idea. It helps keep Stack Exchange sites focused and to the point.

At the same time however, many times I have questions come up that require discussion. Something like "Which programming language should I learn first" is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, but could get a reasonably helpful answer on other forums like DreamInCode.net, Programming Forums, or maybe even Reddit. It seems like it would be more efficient to create a list of forums that we can redirect users with these sorts of questions to.

For example, instead of simply closing the example question above about a first programming language, could it be closed with something like "Stack Overflow is not a site for discussion based questions, but you can try asking about it on <'better-alternative-website'>"?

As far as the idea suggested in [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff), the idea would be similar, but instead of creating an alternative on Stack Exchange itself, questions closed as not constructive could include a "suggested place to ask" link, which would be specific to each Stack Exchange site (Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange redirects to the Raspberry Pi forums, Arduino to Arduino forums, etc.)

Comment: FWIW, if the asker is a thinker, they could greatly narrow their question down to something that has a definite answer with some good amount of research.

Comment: This always seems a strange concept to me. The person posts a question in the wrong place and then expect the community to do the research for them into where to post it. "Where can I post this question?" The answer should be "Why should we do your research for you? If you couldn't be bothered reading up on the site you were posting on in the first place.".

Comment: You say that creating such a list would be "more efficient", but for whom?

Comment: @ArthurFischer, more efficient for the community, because we can redirect users somewhere where they can ask their questions, and less time is spent closing discussion questions, since they will hopefully ask subjective questions on the site that they were redirected to.

Comment: I definitely see how this would cut down on time spent arguing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some communities do such a thing on their Meta.

- [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Super User questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)
- [Where can I have subjective discussions about programming?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/where-can-i-have-subjective-discussions-about-programming)