# Where do I ask opinionated technical questions regarding code?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about [code-style](/questions/tagged/code-style) and [code-quality](/questions/tagged/code-quality)?

I use Stackoverflow to ask programming questions that I believe have a correct technical answer.

I've assumed that [Programmers Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a place where opinions and real life experience could be shared to help me reach a general consensus on what was best to do.  However, each time I post there, I often get pressure to close the post based on it being opinionated.  Well of course it's somewhat opinionated.  How else do you discuss [code-style](/questions/tagged/code-style) and [code-quality](/questions/tagged/code-quality) without having opinions?

Here are my two most recent posts:
 1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289256/does-applying-a-prefix-to-member-variables-make-sense-in-c
 2. [Should I initialize C structs via parameter, or by return value?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290232/should-i-initialize-c-structs-via-parameter-or-by-return-value)

*One of them is closed, and the newest one has pressure to close.

Are these the right questions I should be reserving for Programmers Exchange?

Comment: Related/dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff?s=1|2.3403

Comment: Related (not dupe): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299578/1768232

Comment: @anna-lear, why did you remove 3 completely relevant tags, and add site-recommendation without providing an explanation?  I'm not recommending we change any of the sites.  I'm asking about the relationship between Stackoverflow/Programmers SE, Programmers SE in particular, and questions being closed there.

Comment: @TrevorHickey "site-recommendation" is *the* tag to use when your question is "where should I ask this type of question".

Comment: @AnnaLear Ok, that's what I want then! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I voted to close the one question that is already closed, but support the second question that currently has two votes. In fact, I upvoted that question.

Asking about code style is "primarily opinion-based" pretty much everywhere. Sure, there are a few guidelines that most people will agree on, but by and large you are inviting a religious war on the scale of vi v. emacs when you discuss code style preferences.

Your first question would be rightly closed as "primarily opinion-based" at any of the technology SE sites with which I am at least slightly familiar.

Your second question is *almost* in the same boat but in my opinion it has one saving grace that hinges on the *behavior* of the code. This is not about style so much as semantics, specifically, "what will the compiler do and does one of these options make my code *safer*?"

I believe your second question is on-topic at programmers (other community members may disagree). It is a conceptual question about programming. It is not saying "this code does not work" in fact the presence of the code is there only to illustrate your question. A good answer will discuss the behavior of the compiler and what the tradeoffs are. If you read the answers posted to the question, they show exactly this: the compiler may emit different code, and one option is safer than the other.

While not necessarily a *great* question within the context of what is on-topic at Programmers, I do not believe it should be closed, either.

Comment: Thanks.  That distinction is a lot more clear to me now.  I'll save the opinions for other parts of the internet.

Comment: @TrevorHickey thanks for taking the time to learn. Some people see their question get closed and get upset, rather than asking for feedback to improve. I admit SE can be a bit tricky at times when asking questions, and not all questions are a good fit here. I should know, I have a few deleted questions on my account...

Answer (score 6):

As @Snowman says, some questions like this will be closed. But I would try asking them at [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The tour for Code Review says it is for . . .

> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases

Some questions there can be slightly more subjective than other SE sites.

Comment: That's exactly the SE I would have used had I known about Code Review before.  Good to know.

Comment: @TrevorHickey if you're going to post there, better make sure that question meets all ["six yes" requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) listed in their Help Center. "Is code included directly in my question..." etc

Comment: @TrevorHickey I would also highlight the third of the "six yes" requirements: "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?" which in the case of your second question it would not _as you asked it in that question_. As always, asking a meta question or asking for help in chat first when asking a question on a new (to you) SE site is always a positive step to take.