# Where should I ask people what timepicker and datepicker they use?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have spent 20 mins trying to work out where to ask this but cannot find where.

I know it is NOT appropriate for Stack Overflow.

I have a datepicker and a timepicker that I will be making extensive use of, so they are very important. I had one working "perfectly" and the other good enough - or so I thought. The perfect one on an Android phone is a pain - almost unusable.

So tweaking these two small bits of programming have cost me well over 10 hours programming (I am fairly amateurish) and to get them "right" would be another 10 hours.

There must be somewhere I can just ask "Anyone found a Bootstrap friendly timepicker that works properly on iPhone and Android phones? And if you are feeling kind what JS did you use to launch them?".

I know I am delighted to share with people things that have worked for me but where should I ask for help in a general way like this?

PS And yes I have been through about 10 "Where should I ask" questions.

PPS I also checked out https://stackexchange.com/sites. I find this less than useful. A simple text listing with a brief description would be really welcome. The sites seem to be in no particular order and to see what they refer to you have to click on them individually. I really did not find this page usable - if you already know what you want maybe fine (and it is certainly pretty) but for a comparative newb (surely the target market) I found it a struggle - Just a bit of user feedback.

EDIT: For those coming after the answer looks like [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
as recommend by the wise and learned @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ. And n o this is not a duplicate of a question asking for Polls. I was wanting to talk to real people which I shall do now :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: Next time it'll take you five hours.  The time after that, one.  But if you never do it yourself, you'll never improve.  Consider this a learning experience.

Comment: Err no because I'm still stuck on the datepicker and the timepicker is fine on a PC but screwed on Chrome on Andriod. (So I have to try and find and understand ANOTHER one). I am not trying to "learn" here (I am doing plenty of that already - see the excellent help I got on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726202/how-to-use-bootstrap-dropdown-as-an-html-form-select/) I am trying to ask if others have found a picker that works.  If someone had said that picker worked well on a PC but it really does't work on an iPhone - I would have saved all that time. Thanks for your thoughts. ATB Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title and contents don't exactly match.

To answer your title:

> Where should I ask people what timepicker and datepicker they use?

**Nowhere**, at least on any Stack Exchange Q&A site. This is 'primarily opinion based' and will be instantly closed on any site you ask it on. It just isn't the type of question for the SE Model.

Your only other options are to use a forum (no idea which one... Reddit? Quora?), or get 20 rep on a site and use chat -- there's a link to chat in the topbar, under the 'Stack Exchange' button. Some people may be able to help you there.

---

Your question in the body:

> There must be somewhere I can just ask "Anyone found a Bootstrap friendly timepicker that works properly on iPhone and Android phones? And if you are feeling kind what JS did you use to launch them?".

### Yes!

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) accepts questions asking for libraries and stuff like timepickers, datepickers, etc... but we have very strict guidelines, so please read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/2675) before you post a question. Make sure you have a list of requirements, anything you may have tried, and why they didn't work, etc...

Comment: ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thanks for your useful input. I do think that the ban on "what do you use" is daft but I don't make the rules! The steer to SR is HUGELY helpful. BTW your name  - ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - is that in Burmese or Lao.. a mix or what? Thanks buster

Comment: @OldMauiMan It's 'canadian syllabics': canadian syllabics sha, canadian syllabics blackfoot no, canadian syllabics carrier yu , canadian syllabics west-cree lo. (I'm not canadian or anything btw -- just wanted some cool letters that look like 'shub' ;P

Comment: Well that is very clever and you are obviously a man (woman) with too much time on your hands :-)

Answer (score -1):

Nowhere in the Stack Exchange network. This, according to the SE rules, is being "primarily opinion-based". The definition of "primarily opinion-based" is:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

(The opinion-based questions are only accepted there, on Meta, and all the per-site metas - and only regarding Stack Exchange itself.)

Comment: You need the rep to back this up but going to one of the chats could work for this.

Comment: I am NOT asking for opinions I'm asking for experience. The timepicker for example - either someone could say "great on a PC but works crap on Android" or they might say "to cure the Android problem all you have to do is ...." I am not here as an academic exercise I am trying to build something that I have spent a long time on. I am old and learning new stuff is more difficult for me now. I am NOT trying to embark on a new career I am simply trying to build the third version of a useful, moderately complicated program/app. Why are people here so sanctimonious? Why not just be helpful and kind?