# Should we have another site for frameworks (and alike) recommendations?

Tags: discussion, software-recs-se

There is [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Is the site appropriate for stuff related to requesting frameworks and libraries? Or should we have another site for that (e.g. name it Frameworks Recommendations or stuff alike)?

I can ask stuff there like: *I need a software satisfying W, X, Y, and Z*, but I'd like -some day- ask like: *I need a Python library satisfying W, X, Y, and Z*. The audience may be (and perhaps will be) different.

Is that website on-topic for stuff like that? Or should we open another proposal for that?

**No**: It's not about asking for a giga-dump for subjectivish questions. The linked-to-dupe question was written and answered with an old mindset and without Software Recommendations in mind. Also it does not consider this specific kind of questions but all the crap in one place. So, no, [The Fourth Place ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff) is not an appropriate dupe mark for this question.

Comment: Not duplicate. That question was not written with SR in mind.

Comment: Your question asks first about the scope of [softwarerecs.se] so might be better asked at [meta.softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 3):

Such questions asking for various software libraries and frameworks are on-topic at Software Recommendations. [I've asked such a question myself.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23304/16399)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) of [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), you can ask questions about:

> recommendations of software to accomplish a task.

Though these recommendation must follow their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and must have a purpose and some objective requirements. [Asking for alternates](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) must meet the requirements here though the question you want to ask might be closed for being Too Broad of a question.