# Is there a way to ask for "Getting Started" information-source recommendations that is not off-topic

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to learn about a paradigm totally new to me. I don't have enough experience to formulate specific questions yet. The area is one which has undergone significant change over the years.  Web searches return info on mostly abandoned approaches, and published books on the subject are outdated, which, as a novice in the area, I don't discover until I've wasted time exploring the abandoned approach or wasted time and money on the outdated book(s). Is there a way to ask for pointers to online "Getting Started" resources that won't immediately get shut down as off-topic?

Comment: related : [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/201151)