# Where do I ask about the cheapest way to print a single copy of a book?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have the following question that I'd like to post somewhere:

> What is the cheapest way to print a single copy of a public domain book?
>
> The Shabara Bhashya is an important text of Hindu philosophy, containing the traditional proof that Hinduism is true, but unfortunately it's out of print.  It's in the public domain and available as [a PDF on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/shabarabhasyavol032868mbp), but I'd like a physical copy of it.  My question is, what is the cheapest way to print a single copy of a book like this?
>
> I've found sites where you can print a single copy of a book if you upload a text PDF of the book, but in this case the PDF consists of image scans, not text.  (And OCR would produce a garbled mess, as there are a lot of Indian words in the book.)  So is there any way to print a public-domain book if you have have a PDF consisting of scanned images?

Now if the Stackexchange network had a "Service Recommendations" site, similar to Hardware Recommendations and Software Recommendations, that would be the ideal place.  But there isn't such a site.  So my question is, are there any sites where my question would be on-topic?

Comment: Probably in the **chatroom of** any SE site where the users are familiar with books and printing; [english.se], [academia.se], [languagelearning.se], [writers.se], [linguistics.se] etc.

Answer (score 4):

Its a product/service recommendation, and somewhat objective. For example, you might end up finding a local print shop (and choose to do a simple ring binding, or even a hardback), or finding a POD provider like lulu .

Traditionally, pre SR/HR, we'd point people at chat for questions of that sort but of course you'd need to be familiar with/find a suitable chat. Popping into a random chat is unlikely to yield results of course.

So, no real site there, and even if a site existed for such service recommendations, it is going to be a much more precise and very localised question than most.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [comment by @NVZ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298181/where-do-i-ask-about-the-cheapest-way-to-print-a-single-copy-of-a-book/298182#comment967969_298181) that the only place within the SE network that such a service recommendation question might be welcome is in the chat room of a site "where the users are familiar with books and printing".

At one time it looked like more recommendations sites might follow in the footsteps of Software Recommendations (graduated) and Hardware Recommendations (beta) but these [additional recommendations sites seem to all have faltered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268486/215590).