# Where should I post about self development issues?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to have people assess the situation for me as third parties and give me advice on a very personal matter.

**Should I drop university and start a full-time job?**

It makes more sense to just look at [my earlier-posted topic](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/off-topic-should-i-drop-university-and-switch-to-a-full-time-job) on *Interpersonal Skills*.

Comment: no one except you can answer that one ... and to show you a answer path, I fear its not online you will find it

Comment: There isn't a Stackexchange website for your question.

Comment: The fact that this is such personal advice makes it a bad fit for SE, where the idea is to write content that will be useful to future visitors, not just the OP.

Comment: Some sites do allow more subjective content. It's also possible to rephrase the question more broadly (to be more useful to others) as "What should I consider when deciding whether to complete my degree or start full-time work in software development." I don't know that any of our sites cover this but it might be an option.

Comment: @Catija I'd upvote that as an answer:  of course, in such a form, you'd get entirely different answers from either Academia or Workplace …

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Comment: Even though the question is invalid for stackexchange policy, you can still get away with this one on "Quora".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with something like this is, it's exceptionally broad, and really, you're the only person who really knows all your options.

It's also much too important a decision to rely on random strangers to make.

I'd split this up if I was asking it.

Dropping out is a serious decision. Can you take a break from school while looking for work? (I'd talk to a student councillor here? - or maybe academia, but really the student councillor)

Do you *already* have a job or are you going to speculatively quit school? Have you any serious prospects? (Job hunting can be a pain).

While I love the internet, this is really one of those problems that needs a *boots on the ground* approach. This isn't a crashing PC. *This is the rest of your life*.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, you would be very, very lucky to find an old, trusted friend who would be able to give you sound advice on a question like that...

...The chances of you finding a sane answer on the 'Net are slim to none.

Oh, sure you can ask that on a site like Quora - they already have tons of questions [similar to that](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-worth-taking-a-year-off-from-college-to-work-at-a-startup-Do-you-think-it-would-be-hard-to-transition-back-to-college-after-a-year) and those questions tend to get many... uh... responses.

But if you do go that route, I would take any responses you get with a grain of salt the size of a Humvee. [For all of the reasons Journeyman gives.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300835/where-should-i-post-about-self-development-issue/300836#300836)

If you want folks around here to help - and I get it, we're all pretty awesome and helpful - then you'll want to skip asking *what you should do* and focus on gathering concrete information that'll help you make a sensible decision on your own. Or... At least a decision that you can live with. Questions like,

- [Salary expectations with and without a degree](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/salary-expectations-without-degree)
- [How to study more effectively](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31588/what-can-a-student-who-is-already-studying-hard-do-to-improve-low-grades)
- [What does your experience count for if you're self-taught](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44433/how-much-weight-is-given-to-self-taught-programming-skills)