# Is there a place to ask if a computing term is old fashioned?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wrote a question today where I stated that I was "writing to disk" and wondered if that sounded old fashioned. I wanted to ask for opinions and poll what others felt and to see if other terms made more sense such as "writing to a file", depending on the context.

This is a programming related question on writing to a file on disk. I understand that opinion-based questions are off-topic for all of the sites that I thought about asking it on.

I know that we have *English Language & Usage* but I felt that it wasn't appropriate there either because I wanted to query other programmers.

Am I correct to believe that Stack Exchange as a whole is not the appropriate place to ask this kind of question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a high rep user at ELU (and also a programmer). I think the question will be on-topic, as long as you follow these rules:

- Make sure you're not asking for opinions.
- Include your research that you've done so far on the topic (this is to avoid your question being closed with [this close reason](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5459/191178)). In your case, I would check to see how often (and in what context) the phrase is being used with tools like [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams), [Google Books Search](https://books.google.com/) (which is related to NGram), and just a plain old search of the internet. Be sure to include what you found in your question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not very active on ELU, but they have a [computing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing) tag, with questions on computing terms. It would seem that your question would fit there too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a borderline one for [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).  There are several questions there regarding the meaning of obsolete terms but none (yet) regarding whether or not a term is 'old fashioned'.

It could be worth asking on the [meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/) or [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs) of that site to gauge opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as ELU user, it is very likely on-topic on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com). There's even a tag which tackles questions of the sort. The [contemporary English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contemporary-english) tag. However as all SE sites it's not very friendly to questions which *poll what others felt*. As Laurel already points out a certain prior research would be necessary for your question to be on-topic.