# Undeleting a question as opposed to posting anew (possibly elsewhere)

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, software-engineering-se

I recently posted a question on the Software Engineering site ([Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380417/does-syncing-bank-or-credit-card-account-data-have-any-direct-costs)) that was deleted fairly quickly. The on-hold reason while it was active had noted that they believed I was seeking a software recommendation and that questions of that nature were off-topic. I revised the question to remove the part that was misinterpreted and tried to keep the core of what I was after in focus.

The post consistent of a short background of my research/experience that led me to the question, along with my guess/assumption of what a possible answer could be. Although I tried to look into answers prior to posting, I couldn't find anything through Google. It's entirely possible my search terms are too broad as "bank" "integration" and "sync" tended to flow more into features of banks for things like bill-pay.

I still feel like the question serves a purpose and should have a potential answer for those who may be experienced in this type of field. However, I can't tell if my question is still considered off-topic, or if it was just deleted because of the initial burst of deletion/down votes.

**Question**:

- In situations where a question seems like it may have been incorrectly deleted, what is the best approach for continuing through with the question?
- Should questions like this be entirely rewritten and posted anew; or revised and try to request for it to be undeleted?
- Would it be more reasonable to try a next-best site that may also be able to answer the question?

This is my first experience with a question of mine getting shut down, but I sincerely thought I addressed the initial concern that came from my question's wording. Just trying to figure out how to approach this the right way. I've listed this as discussion as I feel opinions or "I believe" answers could be what surfaces from this.

**Deleted Question and Close/Deletion Reason:** 
[image: Software Engineering: Deleted Question]
[image: Deletion Result and Reason]

Comment: Sorry, I will try to get one attached. I thought it may be visible to everyone with a direct link since I could see it. Although, that's probably because I posted the question.

Comment: Who deleted it? A moderator or 3 users with delete privileges?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be all that much of a software engineering question; the first point is about bank policies, and the second is very much a software request.

Comment: @rene It looks like the hold and deletion was user-requested. I've added that screenshot as well in case it affects my particular case. However, I'm guessing it's more fitting that my question is more of how to approach these as a whole instead of just me =).

Comment: @Xrylite how it is deleted does mater for your second bullet, a bit.

Comment: @fbueckert I can certainly understand if I'm tunnel-visioning my question and it's still unclear. The goal is in that scenario was to understand whether an integration like that is something that is provided via the bank apis themselves; a third-party service; or if it's possible each integrate their own way. If it is site-by-site, then an answer would be impossible if I were asking how. For clarity, I am not working on or trying to implement this. It's purely understanding and curiosity.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SE.SE, so this could be mistaken: we're generally not huge fans of, "How do I go about doing this?" type questions on any site.  There needs to be something more than pure curiosity for there to be a problem to solve.  Your question was closed as asking for a tool recommendation, which I suspect is due to the last bullet point.  The first one seems *awful* broad, along with not actually being about software in the slightest.  There doesn't seem to be anything there that would fit on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you don't have the [Informed badge](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/129/informed) on Software Engineering. That's *usually* a sign of users who think "I have a question about X and I think it matches the topic of that site, so I'm going to ask it there." They couldn't be more wrong; many sites have strict rules about what is [on topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and what not.

It's quite common to close off-topic questions, but *not* to delete them (unless they're blatantly off-topic, like a soccer question on a programming site). Deletion is usually left to the automatic process nicknamed [Roomba](/help/roomba), so the OP has 9 days or so to edit it into something that's acceptable to the community.

I'm not sure if this can be edited into a valid Software Engineering question. The second part is essentially a [recommendation question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/295232) and these generally don't work on the Stack Exchange Q&A model (there are [two exceptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268486/295232) but I doubt you'll get a good answer there.) The first question is something I'd ask my bank, and not some bunch of people on the Internet, no matter how knowledgeable they are.

Were I have to questions like this, I'd try to search for a chatroom to see if anybody has experience with this; otherwise, I'd try other websites on the Internet and return to Stack Exchange once I have more concrete questions about the implementation.

Comment: I will absolutely go through the Tour to see if I can figure out why what I think was relevant may not be. I did read through the on-topic section a bit after it had already been closed, but I understand that was the wrong order. I am understanding more how the second part of my question seems like I'm still wanting a service. Lastly, I can try contacting a bank to see, but the curiosity is still how the automatic syncing works across many thousands of banks and credit unions. Greatly appreciate the rounded feedback!