# Where would I ask a question about creating smart TV applications?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to decide if creating a smart TV application is the way to go or if I should use some alternative approach like a Raspberry Pi or IoT device.

Which Stack Exchange site would be the most appropriate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Answer (score 6):

None; the network cannot support a question like this because it's too broad or imprecise.  That is to say, because there is no "right" answer to this question, there is no way to answer it in an objective and concise fashion.