# Which Stack Exchange for question about comparing "Classical internet routing vs. Swarm intelligence routing"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about comparing "**Classical** internet routing vs. **Swarm** intelligence routing (such as ACO)" as follows:

Here is my question:

> Is it possible to mention the drawbacks/advantages of **Swarm
> routing** (such as Ant routing etc) in comparison with **classical
> routing** algorithms in communication networks in a general view?
>
> In other words, what will we gain if we replace a classical routing
> algorithm with a swarm routing based algorithm?
>
> Can we compare these two type of routing algorithms in a general view
> to mention their to count the drawbacks/advantages? The main purpose
> of this question is to define applications of each of those routing
> approaches. Which one is more decentralized? And which one has more
> efficient performance?
>
> Here is my personal opinion (I am not sure about it) :
>
> **classical** internet routing in **more centralized** than **swarm** routing (such as **ACO** based routing) which does **not** use any
> **routing table and router** to avoid moving towards **centralization** where those routing tables and routers **can be manipulated** (as a **point of failure**). Instead, **classical**
> internet routing may be **faster** than **swarm** based routing.
> Briefly, **classical** may be **more centralized**, but **faster** and
> on the other side, **swarm** based is **more decentralized** but may
> be **slower**. So, **cannot we conclude that Swarm based routing is
> more appropriate for decentralized networks?** Am I wrong?
>
> So, we now can ask that : **Which approach is more decentralized? And
> Which one is faster?**

**Please note** that networkengineering.stackexchange.com says this question is off-topic for networkengineeringstack Exchange.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds pretty opinionated, more than an actual objective question.

Comment: Yes, the question is multidisciplinary between networking, distributed systems , artificial intelligence.

Comment: I'm not saying it's multidisciplinary.  I'm saying there's likely not a real objective answer.  Along with it likely being rather broad.  If Network Engineering wouldn't take it, then I'm not sure where else you might ask this.  There may not be be anywhere on the network where this would be acceptable.

Comment: Problem is that Network Engineering prefers more "business" based questions (as they said) that is **more centralized networking**; however, Swarm based routing could be more suitable for **ad hoc networks** that are very **decentralized**. But Network Engineering believes that **ad hoc** network is not normally used in business. In the next comment, I bring out two comments from Networking Engineering.

Comment: (1) _"Ad hoc networks are not normally used in a business because of the lack of control. Businesses use infrastructure mode for Wi-Fi and centralized control."_ AND (2) _"Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment."_ (by user Ron Maupin.) Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how that's strengthening your question.  Yes, NE.SE won't take it.  Those comments just highlight how opinionated the question is.

Comment: Do I need to modify it? (with keeping the main context of question: i.e. which approach is more decentralized? And which one is faster?)

Comment: I don't think your question as it stands would fit on any site; you're highlighting why it's problematic.  The main context (especially the fast aspect) depends on lots of variables that are likely weighted differently for each reader.  Can you distill it into a specific, objective, focused question?

Comment: In fact, I added the last section to question by asking **"Which approach is more decentralized? And Which one is faster?"** that can shows the target of question: i.e. which approach is more appropriate for more decentralized networks? however, the remained problem is that one approach (swarm based routing) is more related to artificial intelligence and other one (classical routing) is related to classical networking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)