# Where do I go for general Internet website questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to find the right community where I can ask questions about other website communities and their influence in real life, or is it this community?

Comment: Can you give us a couple specific example questions you'd like to ask?

Comment: What I want to know is that are websites organized by people that holds crossover battles legit and factually correct in all fandom communities and the actual verse itself? Or is it only legit within the confines of the website that hosts them? I mean, I just want to know if they are just for fun. Such as Outskirt Battledome, VsBattle, SpaceBattles Forum, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the example. You should [edit] it directly into your question.  The short story is there's nowhere in the StackExchange network where you could ask that question, unfortunately.  If I had to guess at an answer: if it's written by fans, it's fanfiction, and therefore not canon in the verse. Since it's crossover, it's probably not even considered properly in the fanfiction, because non-verse characters appear.  So it's "just for fun".

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, it should really help me out in the long run, and makes my decision to be that much easier. And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s)

Answer (score 7):

Our site [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) deals with *using* the websites of such communities, e.g. Facebook and Twitter; see their [Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you have a more theoretical question about how online communities interact with real life, it might work on [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). Without knowing your actual question it's hard to tell, but I found some interesting questions about social media & real life by just browsing the site, e.g. [What is the effect of Social Media consumption on self-esteem?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/what-is-the-effect-of-social-media-consumption-on-self-esteem)

Comment: What I want to know is that are websites organized by people that holds crossover battles legit and factually correct in all fandom communities and the actual verse itself? Or is it only legit within the confines of the website that hosts them? I mean, I just want to know if they are just for fun. Such as Outskirt Battledome, VsBattle, SpaceBattles Forum, etc?